# Get current test name in BanditCPP

Tags: unit-testing, banditcpp

Is it possible to get the current context and test name in a [BanditCPP](http://banditcpp.org/) spec ?

For example, given example from the web site:

```
describe("a calculator", [&](){
  calculator_ptr calc;

  it("can add", [&](){
    AssertThat(calculator->add(3,2), Equals(5));
  });
});
```

I would like to be able to get the "a calculator" or "can add" string (ie: for logging purpose)

Is there any way to retrieve this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to access this from within tests, and I don't see us adding that functionality.

There is functionality in place for listening to events, such as tests starting, succeeding, failing etc. by implementing a [listener](https://github.com/joakimkarlsson/bandit/blob/master/bandit/listener.h)

There's unfortunately no clean way of telling bandit's run function to use your listener at the moment, but you could look at the [run function](https://github.com/joakimkarlsson/bandit/blob/master/bandit/runner.h#L87) and perhaps craft your own setup in main.

It should definitely be doable to change bandit's run function to be able to accept additional listeners as arguments.